# Viability of low THC cannabis for C-PTSD with past dissociation episodes

Tags: cognitive-psychology

[Passie, et al. (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1002/dta.1377) says cannabis helps against post-traumatic-stress disorder.

In the case of C-PTSD (complex post traumatic stress disorder) combined with past dissociation episodes, is low THC Cannabis Ruderalis varieties a good choice?

Or is it risky?

### References

Passie, T., Emrich, H. M., Karst, M., Brandt, S. D., & Halpern, J. H. (2012). Mitigation of post‐traumatic stress symptoms by Cannabis resin: A review of the clinical and neurobiological evidence. *Drug testing and analysis, 4*(7-8), 649-659. https://doi.org/10.1002/dta.1377

Comment: I will have a look at Passie et al tomorrow to see what they were saying